# Sitecore Upload Window

Tags: sheer-ui

I am currently developing a module where I am using the Sitecore Upload window. Most of the implementation of the Upload window is the same as the one of Package Installation Wizard.

The issue is that when I click on the Upload button, it open the window however, I get **Document Not Found**.

[image]

The code is as follows:

```cs
public static void Upload(ClientPipelineArgs args, Edit fileEdit)
{
    if (!args.IsPostBack)
    {
        UploadForm.Show(ApplicationContext.PackagePath, true);
        args.WaitForPostBack();
    }
    else
    {
        if (!args.Result.StartsWith("ok:", StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
            return;
        string[] strArray = args.Result.Substring("ok:".Length).Split('|');
        if (strArray.Length < 1 || fileEdit == null)
            return;
        fileEdit.Value = strArray[0];
    }
}
```

The code for the `Show` Method

```cs
public static void Show(string directory, bool postback)
{
    Assert.ArgumentNotNull(directory, "directory");
    Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.ShowModalDialog(GetUrl(directory), postback);
}
```

And this calls the `GetUrl` Method

```cs
private static string GetUrl(string directory)
{
    Assert.ArgumentNotNull(directory, "directory");
    var urlString = new UrlString(Constants.UploadFileApp);
    urlString.Append("di", ApplicationContext.StoreObject(directory));
    return urlString.ToString();
}
```

The `Constants.UploadFileApp` has the path `/sitecore/shell/applications/package generator/upload/uploadfile`.

In the Core DB, the path of the uploadfile is `/sitecore/content/Applications/Package Generator/Upload/UploadFile`

**EDIT 1**
This is how the url is being changed
[image]

Comment: Do you have a typo somewhere? Your screenshot says uploadfile**di**

Comment: I thought this was the issue but from the Network Tab on inspect element, the url format is correct, then a 302 redirection is done and remove the (?)

Comment: I have updated the question with the screenshot of the network tab

Comment: Which version of Sitecore are you on?

Comment: It is Sitecore v7.2 rev 141226

Comment: Do you get the same error if use the Upload from Sitecore directly?

Comment: Yes, I have checked it on the Sitecore Package Installation Wizard and I have also implemented the window the same way as the Upload Wizard in the Package Installation Wizard. The only difference is that the path I have specified is from the Core DB while the SItecore Installation Wizard takes it directly from the website folder.

Comment: Have you checked the Permissions on the folder you mentioned above (/sitecore/content/Applications/Package Generator/Upload/UploadFile)?

Comment: Yes, the permission is set to Full Control. Also, the path `sitecore/content/Applications/Package Generator/Upload/UploadFile` is mapped onto `Website\sitecore modules\PackageGenerator\Upload\UploadFile.aspx`

Comment: @HishaamNamooya I think where Kasper was going with his comment was that the query-string param is more likely to be uploadfile**id** than uploadfile**di**

Comment: No, it should be `di` as it stands from directory. I have also decompiled the Sitecore kernel and it is `di`. The `di` contains the guid of the directory of the package folder

Comment: Any way to move UploadFile.aspx to a different folder and see if works?

Comment: @ViniciusDeschamps i am going to change the folder. Right now the page is found in the sitecore module folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out what was the issue.

**Brief Problem Description**

I have been using the same code as the one for the Sitecore Installation Wizard upload UI. The only modification done in the implementation is that  instead of reading the the `ASPX` page, I have created an item which is mapped onto the `ASPX` page and also, it should allowed only CSV file to be uploaded instead of Zip file.

**Solution**

The issue was due to the path I had specified in the Frame SRC

```cs
 private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     this.Upload.Attributes["src"] = Constants.UploadFileApp + WebUtil.GetQueryString();
 }
```

The `Constants.UploadFileApp` value is

```cs
/sitecore/shell/applications/package generator/upload/uploadfile
```

I should have use the following path

```cs
/sitecore/shell/applications/package generator/upload/uploadfile2
```

Because of this, it causes the Form to redirect to itself hence causing the Error Code 302 as shown in the **Inspect Element Network Tab** in the question.

So, I had only need to change the above code to the one below:

```cs
 private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     this.Upload.Attributes["src"] = Constants.UploadFile2App + WebUtil.GetQueryString();
 }
```

where `Constants.UploadFile2App` has the path

`/sitecore/shell/applications/package generator/upload/uploadfile2`

*PS:Sorry for missing some information in the question*

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide more information, are you creating your own dialog, or you want to change existing dialog functionality, if so you have to change inheritance of existing dialog aspfx file, so it points to your own code functionality.

For instance for fileUpload

```
<%@ Page language="c#" CodeBehind="Upload.aspx.cs" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="SitecoreClient.sitecore.shell.Applications.Upload.UploadPage" %>
```

it has to  be pointing to your project namespace and class.

Comment: I have used the same code as Sitecore used to develop the Upload Wizard. I have also posted the answer why I had the document not found issue